# cannot slice r.route (type *[]Route)

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
type routeVerifier struct {
    route *[]Route
}


func (r *routeVerifier) checkUriDuplication(comparer *[]Route, uri string) error {


    for _, e := range *comparer {
        if e.Uri == uri {
            msg := fmt.Sprintf("The uri %s already exist", uri)
            return errors.New(msg)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func (r *routeVerifier) validate() routesErrorLogger {

  errors := routesErrorLogger{}

    for i, e := range *r.route {

        error := newRouteErrorLogger(e.Uri)

    if err := r.checkUri(e.Uri); err != nil {
      error.add(err)
        }

        if err := r.checkUriDuplication(r.route[i:], e.Uri); err != nil {
      error.add(err)
        }

        mv := newMethodsVerifier(&e.Methods)
        if err := mv.validate(); len(err) > 0 {

        }
    }

}
```

the compiler complains:

```
descriptor/route_verifier.go:55:42: cannot slice r.route (type *[]Route)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r.route` is a pointer to a slice, not a slice. `(*r.route)` is a slice, so you have to:

```
(*r.route)[i:]
```

Are you sure you need a pointer to a slice in that struct? That is almost always unnecessary. A slice already contains a pointer to the underlying array. It does not have the data, it is a pointer to the data, along with additional info to define a view on it.

Simply define:

```
type routeVerifier struct {
    route []Route
}
```

The `checkUriDuplication` can be defined to take a `[]Route`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `checkUriDuplication` method. Please check the code again.

Comment: With your suggestion above, I've got `cannot use (*r.route)[i:] (type []Route) as type *[]Route in argument to r.checkUriDuplication`

Comment: That suggests (and indeed the update shows) that you've defined your check-duplication function using a pointer-to-slice, which, as Burak Serdar notes, is almost always unnecessary. You've shot yourself in the foot multiple times, and as you fix each one, the remaining holes become more pressing. :-)

Comment: Why it is unnecessary to define `route *[]Route` in struct. With that definition I can `route` in methods. What is your suggestion?

Comment: @zero_coding see the updates in the answer.

Comment: Now it is clear. Thanks a lot